# How should I make this SQL Query more efficent

Tags: php, loops, select, mysqli

I am searching up a database to find the past 7 days worth of data, accumulated.

It works perfectly, but I currently have seven editions of the same code - so I want to loop it somehow, however if I do that, how do I loop it correctly and name the variables. Aside from naming the variables (day_X_) I think I should be able to loop it 7 times fairly easily...

```
// Get the current day
$graph_day_1_date_lower = date('Y-m-d') . " 00:00";
$graph_day_1_date_upper = date('Y-m-d') . " 23:59";
$graph_day_1_name = date('D') . " (Today)";
/* Successes */
$graph_day_1 = mysqli_query($con, 
   "SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS num FROM `hidden` 
   WHERE submittedtime >= '$graph_day_1_date_lower' 
   AND submittedtime < '$graph_day_1_date_upper' 
   AND u_s_code='C001'") 
 or die(mysqli_error($con));
$graph_day_1_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($graph_day_1);
$graph_day_1_count = $graph_day_1_row['num'];
$graph_total_count = $graph_day_1_count;
/* Errors */
$graph_e_day_1 = mysqli_query($con, 
  "SELECT COUNT(`id`) AS num FROM `hidden` 
  WHERE submittedtime >= '$graph_day_1_date_lower' 
  AND submittedtime < '$graph_day_1_date_upper' 
  AND u_s_code='E001'") 
or die(mysqli_error($con));

$graph_e_day_1_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($graph_e_day_1);
$graph_e_day_1_count = $graph_e_day_1_row['num'];
$graph_e_total_count = $graph_e_day_1_count;
```

I will then print the two total counts for each day

Comment: You want to loop the whole snippet, but with 2 instead of 1 as variable name?

Comment: [Prepare](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) the statement once and reuse it [with different values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Comment: You can use variables in variable names like this: `$i=1; ${"day$i"}=1;`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you would want to do:

```
$today = time(); // or use your upper / lower bounds
$daysToShow = 7;
$dayData = array();

for($i = 0; $i < $daysToShow; $i++){
   $dateToCheck = $today + ($i * 24 * 60 * 60); // add a day each time $i goes up
   $dataArray = mysql_fetch_assoc($yourDataHere); // replace with your mysqli query using $dateToCheck
   $dayData[] = $dataArray; // add to array
}

foreach($dayData as $day){
   echo $day['name']; // print out your info here
}
```